# How to enable and disable page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My project is horizontal scroll only. Which mean X.

`#landscape` is the whole container.

At first, I disable the scroll for `#landscape`.

After that when I clicked `.close-reveal-modal` a `div` fade in.

In this `div` I still can't scroll `$('#landscape')`. 
After that, I want to enable back the scroll for `$('#landscape')` after I close this `.close-reveal-modal` .

I tired to put `$('#landscape').off` which mean enable it. But it doesn't work for me.

```
$('#landscape').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){ // on off means enable and disable
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
})

$('.close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#second_load').fadeIn(300);
    }, 1000);
});

$('#second_load').click(function(){
    $('#second_load').fadeOut(300);

    $('#landscape').off('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){ // on off means enable and disable
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function freeze() {
        var top = $("html").scrollTop() ? $("html").scrollTop() : $("body").scrollTop();
        var left = $("html").scrollLeft() ? $("html").scrollLeft() : $("body").scrollLeft();
        if(window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
            $("html").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        }
        if(window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
            $("html").css("overflow-x", "scroll");
        }
        $("html").css({"width": "100%", "height": "100%", "position": "fixed", "top": -top, "left": -left});
}
function unfreeze() {
        $("html").css("position", "static");
        $("html, body").scrollTop(-parseInt($("html").css("top")));
        $("html, body").scrollLeft(-parseInt($("html").css("left")));
        $("html").css({"position": "", "width": "", "height": "", "top": "", "left": "", "overflow-y": "", "overflow-x": ""});
}
```

Source: https://github.com/HubSpot/vex/issues/155

Comment: I tried your code. I not sure am I apply correctly. But it don't work for me.